# Clicked list element should be highlighted

Tags: jquery

I have a list and I wish whichever element I click on the list should be highlighted. I have used jQuery to accomplish the task but somehow the code isn't working. Please correct my code and kindly explain in detail.

HTML

```
<ul class="nav">
 <li class="active"><a>Link 1</li>
 <li><a>Link 2</li>
 <li><a>Link 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.nav a { cursor: pointer; }
.active { color:#f00;font-weight:bolder; }
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
      $( '.nav li' ).click( function() {
            $( this ).parent().find( '.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
            $( this ).next().addClass( 'active' );
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To highlight the current (clicked) `li`, you need to skip targeting the `next()` element, and add the class to the `li` itself instead:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.nav li').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
ul.nav a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  color: #f00;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="active"><a>Link 1</li>
 <li><a>Link 2</li>
 <li><a>Link 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you

```js
$(function() {
      $( '.nav li' ).click( function() {
            $( '.nav li' ).removeClass( 'active' );
            $( this ).addClass( 'active' );
      });
});
```

```css
ul.nav a { cursor: pointer; }
.active { color:#f00;font-weight:bolder; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
 <li class="active"><a>Link 1</li>
 <li><a>Link 2</li>
 <li><a>Link 3</li>
</ul>
```